# Show that $P$ is divided to simple roots knowing that $a_{k}^2-4a_{k-1}a_{k+1}>0$

Tags: calculus, polynomials

> Let $P(X)=a_0+a_1X+..+a_nX^n\in R[X]$
>
> Assume that  $\forall k, a_k>0$ and $a_{k}^2-4a_{k-1}a_{k+1}>0$
>
> Show that $P$  is divided to simple roots in $R[X]$. i.e. $P(X)=C(X−\alpha_1)\cdots(x−\alpha_n)$, where $\alpha_i, \quad 1 \le i \leq n$ are distinct.

I'm stuck wigh this problem, I cannot get any good idea for this.

I tried to use the fact that, 
$$
\sigma_{k}=(-1)^{k}\cdot\frac{a_{n-k}}{a_{n}}
$$
where $\sigma_{k}$ are [The elementary symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial)

But it did not lead nowhere.

In fact I do not see how to connect the fact that $a_{k}^2-4a_{k-1}a_{k+1}>0$ and the result I have to prove.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assumption can be slightly generalized to $a_k>0$ and
$$
a_k^2> q^2\,a_{k-1}a_{k+1}.
$$
for all $k=1,...,d-1$ for some $q\ge2$.
Because these are finitely many conditions on the coefficients, there also exist $q>2$ for the given set of coefficients.

Define $b_k=q^{k^2}\,a_k$, then 
$$
b_{k-1}b_{k+1}=q^{2k^2+2}\,a_{k-1}a_{k+1}< q^{2k^2}\,a_k^2=b_k^2
$$
Rewriting that relation as
$$
\frac{b_{k-1}}{b_k}<\frac{b_k}{b_{k+1}}
$$
one recognizes that the sequence of these fractions is strictly monotonically increasing.

Now fix some $m$ and consider values 
$$
q^{2m}\,\frac{b_{m-1}}{b_m}=\frac{qa_{m-1}}{a_m}< x< \frac{a_m}{qa_{m+1}}=q^{2m}\,\frac{b_m}{b_{m+1}}
$$

> **Proposition 1:** For these short intervals, $p(-x)$ is non-zero and has the sign $(-1)^m$.

Consider the quotient 
$$
\frac{p(-x)}{(-x)^m}=\dots+(-a_{m-3}\,x^{-3}+a_{m-2}\,x^{-2})+(-a_{m-1}\,x^{-1}+a_m-a_{m+1}\,x)+(a_{m+2}\,x^2-a_{m+3}\,x^3)+...
$$
The claim of the proposition is proved if this fraction is positive.

> **Lemma 2:** All these groups of terms on the right of the fraction are positive.

Check first the group at the center around $a_m$, then the groups to the left and finally to the right. If at one end the group is incomplete, because one of $m$ or $\deg p-m$ is even, then the only term in this group of one is positive.
\begin{align}
-a_{m-1}\,x^{-1}+a_m-a_{m+1}\,x
&> a_m\,(-q^{-1}+1-q^{-1})
\\
&=
a_m\, q^{-1}\,(q-2)
\\&
\ge0
\\[1.2em]%\hline
(-a_{m-2p-1}\,x^{-2p-1}+a_{m-2p}\,x^{-2p})
&=a_{m-2p}\,x^{-2p-1}\,\left(x-\frac{a_{m-2p-1}}{a_{m-2p}}\right)
\\
&> 
a_{m-2p}\,x^{-2p-1}\,\left(q^{2m\,}\frac{b_{m-1}}{b_m}-q^{2m-4p-1}\,\frac{b_{m-2p-1}}{b_{m-2p}}\right)
\\
&>
a_{m-2p}\,x^{-2p-1}\,q^{2m}\,\left(1-q^{-4p-1}\right)\,\frac{b_{m-1}}{b_{m}}
\\&> 0
\\[1.2em]%\hline
a_{m+2p}\,x^{2p}-a_{m+2p+1}\,x^{2p+1}
&=
a_{m+2p+1}\,x^{2p}\,\left(\frac{a_{m+2p}}{a_{m+2p+1}}-x\right)
\\
&>
a_{m+2p+1}\,x^{2p}\,q^{2m}\,\left(q^{4p+1}-1\right)\,\frac{b_{m}}{b_{m+1}}
\\&> 0
\end{align}
One sees that in the sum there is a lower positive bound on $\frac{p(-x)}{(-x)^m}$ for the selected interval.

**Conclusion:** Since $p(0)=a_0>0$ and the sign of $p(-x)$ for very large $x$ is $(-1)^{\deg p}$, one identifies $\deg p$ disjoint intervals
$$
\left(-\infty, -\frac{a_{\deg p-1}}{qa_{\deg p}}\right],\;
\left[-\frac{qa_{\deg p-2}}{a_{\deg p-1}},-\frac{a_{\deg p-2}}{qa_{\deg p-1}}\right],\;...,\;
\left[-\frac{qa_{1}}{a_{2}},-\frac{a_{1}}{qa_{2}}\right],\;
\left[-\frac{qa_{0}}{a_{1}},0\right]
$$
on the negative ray where $p$ changes its sign and thus must have a real root in between. This already is the number of all roots of $p$, so that the factorization claim follows.

---

**Remark:** This question is closely related to the Newton polygon of the polynomial. Indeed, the assumption leads to the equivalent formulation that
$$
-\ln(a_k)=\alpha \,k^2+\phi(k)
$$
where $\alpha=\ln q$ and $\phi$ is a convex function on the integers. The condition on $x$ is related to the slopes of supporting linear functions at the corner $(m,\phi(m))$ of the graph of $\phi$.

Some of that is discussed in the articles of Malajovich/Zubelli on the geometry of the Graeffe iteration resp. the tangent Graeffe iteration.

Comment: I first thought it was required to gain an additional edge. But the estimates below to not really depend on it, one just has to check which inequalities are or have to be strict when using the original inequalities. -- The inequality $a_k^2\ge q^2a_{k-1}a_{k+1}$ is satisfied by $q=2$ by the assumption. Also, for each $k$ there are $q>2$ satisfying this inequality. So for each $k$ there is an open interval around $2$ of admissible values. The intersection of finitely many open intervals is still an open interval, so there are $q>2$ satisfying all inequalities.

Comment: I changed the inequalities so that the original formulation is included for $q=2$. I left $q$ since for me it adds structure, one can follow the propagation of the factor in the assumption through the computation and can distinguish it from other occurring numbers $2$ or $4$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_0=1$ and define (Following Hardy)
$$a_n=\frac{1}{B_1B_2\cdots B_n},B_k<B_{k+1}$$

Huchinson [1] showed if $a_{k}^2-4a_{k-1}a_{k+1}>0$, then that there exists a simple zero of the polynomial in the interval
$$\left(-\sqrt{B_{2\nu}B_{2\nu+1}},-\sqrt{B_{2\nu-1}B_{2\nu}}\right),\qquad \nu=1,2,...$$

Please refer to [1] for details.

[1] Hutchinson, J. I. "On a remarkable class of entire functions." Transactions of the American Mathematical Society 25.3 (1923): 325-332.